# Dart files generated by swagger working on flutter platform

Tags: dart, flutter, swagger

I am trying to develop a mobile application with Flutter, I want to use swagger to get the web services. As long as flutter uses the Dart language, swagger generates a Dart files codegen.
I want to know that if Dart files generated by swagger working on flutter platform or no?

Answer (score 2):

Sure they do.

Pure Dart code always works in Flutter.

There are only two exception

- code depends on reflection
- code depends on `dart:html`

but Swagger does not depend on one of these.

Comment: So, how can i use the  Dart files generated by swagger in my mobile app ?

Comment: How can you not use them? Just generate and import. Perhaps you are looking for https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/open_api (Swagger was renamed to OpenAPI)

Comment: yeah, i import it into my project and i added  the dependencie "open_api: ^2.0.1" in pubspec.yaml, i still have many errors that i succeeded to solve them.
Now, i want to know how can i use the Api in my project

Comment: Then please post the errors. I don't know what problems you face until you explain them.

Comment: The tests might help to get an idea how to use https://github.com/stablekernel/open-api-dart/blob/master/test/v3_test.dart

Comment: I found a solution for errors, i just restart Android Studio.
My problem now, it's how can i use the mobileApi in my app. For example, in main.dart when i put "import './dart-client-generated' an error appear as following " Target of URI doesn't exist: './dart-client-generated'. The "dart-client-generated" is the Dart files generated by swagger imported in my project

Comment: Hard to tell with this information. What is `dart-client-generated` supposed to be? Does the file exist? You need to add the `.dart` extension to imports.

Comment: "dart-client-generated"  is the Dart files generated by swagger imported in my project that contains the Apis.i put this "import './dart-client-generated/lib/api/mobile_api.dart';" and the same error appear. I'm really lost

Comment: The import `/dart-client-generated/lib/api/mobile_api.dart'` is not valid. I don't know what you try to accomplish. If `dart-client-generated` is another package, you would need to add it to dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` like explained in https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages with `dart-client-generated` instead of `transmography` and `../dart-client-generated` as path and then import it with `import 'package:dart-client-generated/api/mobile_api.dart';`

Comment: I did everything you said, in pubspec.yaml below 
dependencies i put  dart-client-generated:
    path: ./dart-client-generated, an error appear as following 
"Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_app_ws...  Error on line 1, column 7 of dart-client-generated/pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't match expected name "dart-client-generated".
name: swagger"

Comment: Then `dart-client-generated` is probably not a pub package. You can make it one by adding a minimal `pubspec.yaml` or move the code somewhere into `lib/...` of your application.

Comment: I moved the "dart-client-generated" into lib/ , then i put this "import './dart-client-generated/lib/api/mobile_api.dart';" in main.dart, this error appear "The imported library ''./dart-client-generated/lib/api/mobile_api.dart'' can't have a part-of directive."

Comment: You probably import the wrong file. Is there a `*.dart` file in `./dart-client-generated/lib/`? Then probably this is the one you should import.

Comment: There has to be a *.dart file that does *not* contain `part of ...`. Actually the file `part of ...` points to should be the file that you can import.

Comment: Yeah, it's worked now, i just put this import 'package:flutter_app_ws/dart-client-generated/lib/api.dart';
thank you very much for your time and your reply

Comment: Glad to hear :)